# Combining CSS3 Not Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select all links except those that are internal AND mailto links AND anchor links (#)
So I want to combine selectors so they will exclude X, Y and Z. However I can not figure out how to join them.

```
a:not([href*="myurl"]) { }
```

This CSS finds all links that don't contain 'myurl' however it then finds mailto: and anchor (#) links as well and I would like to exclude this from the selector.

I have to use a not selector to find all URLs outside my site as there is no way to my knowledge to say 'all sites outside my own' without using a not. 
Is there a way I can make it like

```
a:not([href*="myurl OR # OR mailto"]) { }
```

The full code uses :hover and :after as well if that matters:

```
a:not([href*="myurl"]):hover:after { }
```

This needs to be done fully in CSS not jquery/javascript. And I can't add classes to the urls.

Is it at all possible? (Cross browser isn't that important. Chrome + Firefox would be good enough)

My current work around is to target the other links using `not([href*="http:// "]) { }` but this is not preferable because it means overwriting the changes again which doesn't always work because one might have been `color: red` and the other `color: blue` and I can't make them go back to the original colours (among other reasons)

Answer (score 13):

You can exclude them simply by adding more `:not()` selectors:

```
a:not([href*="myurl"]):not([href*="#"]):not([href*="mailto"]) { }
```

For the `:hover:after` state, simply append it like so:

```
a:not([href*="myurl"]):not([href*="#"]):not([href*="mailto"]):hover:after { }
```

Also, since this is CSS3, I'd recommend that you denote `:after` as `::after` using double colons instead, just to make it clear that you're chaining a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) after a series of pseudo-classes, but it's not absolutely required and whichever you use won't make a difference in terms of browsers:

```
a:not([href*="myurl"]):not([href*="#"]):not([href*="mailto"]):hover::after { }
```